# How to retrieve real pixel's HDR colors associated with CIImage

Tags: core-image

Can someone advice me
how to retrieve real pixel's high dynamic range(cn be > 1.f) colors from CIImage ?

This method returns data scaled between[0...1]

```
NSBitmapImageRep * rep = [[[NSBitmapImageRep alloc] initWithCIImage:[self ciImage]] autorelease];
return [rep colorAtX:imgPt.x y:imgPt.y];
```

Thank You.